# D compile-time variable homogeneous arrays

Tags: d, compile-time

D2.056

```
void f(string[] names...)
{
    foreach (name; names)
    {
        mixin("string " ~ name ~ " = name;");
    }
}

int main()
{
    f("a", "b");
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this not work? It complains about 'name' not being compile-time readable, but that is a false statement. The content of 'names' is known at compile-time, since it is {"a", "b"};

I am trying to make a bind with a library, and the passed function names must be defined and pointed to the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions must be valid for both compilation and compile-time execution. Obviously `f` is not compilable.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could either make `names` a template argument (which would make the `foreach` static), or make `f` build a string and mixin the result at `f`'s call site.

Comment: How would I ensure, with the templated version, that the tuple passed is indeed homogeneous and of a type compatible to string? Because that check is lost when converting to the templated version.